Windows 11 Home - Unable to run django-admin
I have looked through several post regarding either:
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized
or
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
I am trying to run django-admin startproject...and again I have tried it several ways and keep getting one of the two above errors.
I've used the full path to python, I have used variations of that command that I have seen in several post but none are working.
I am able to run "python -m django --version"  and I get 5.1.
I can run a .py file in the terminal window fine.  But can't use "django-admin".
Here is one of the full errors:
C:\Users\Famil\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Alejandro\Django\django-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Please advise, this is so crazy.
Cheers

I'm not really a windows user, but the core issue about your problem is that you need to understand why you don't have the command in your terminal/shell. And on the second, understand to interprete Error messages. is there a file called django-admin.py? Is that file in the folder C:\Alejandro\Django\ ? -> [Errno 2] No such file or directory And then the windows know how kicks in. Do you use an old-style cmd? powershell? How does a command like cd,dir becomes available in a terminal/shell? Where are they saved? To which sys/user-PATH you have to add them? How? So. Keep going!

Well, I found a post:
django-admin: The term 'django-admin' i
I put in the below code and it worked!
Hope this helps someone.  Cheers
python -m django startproject myfirstproject


Do you believe this question is at the core a duplicate of that other question? If you do, you might consider closing this one as a duplicate. Up to you though.

This will help someone, but it doesn't solve the root cause, since you make a specific execution instead of having the shortcut available as a command. Saying: I put the code below, doesn't make awareness of what's actually happening, which would be helpful.

The docs recommend installing Django in a virtual environment. You don't seem to be using one.
To create a virtual environment for your project, open a new command prompt, navigate to the folder where you want to create your project and then enter the following:
py -m venv project-name

This will create a folder called ‘project-name’ if it does not already exist and set up the virtual environment. To activate the environment, run:
project-name\Scripts\activate.bat

The virtual environment will be activated and you’ll see “(project-name)” next to the command prompt to designate that. Each time you start a new command prompt, you’ll need to activate the environment again.
Then go ahead and install Django by running:
py -m pip install Django

This will download and install the latest Django release.
After the installation has completed, you can verify your Django installation by executing django-admin --version in the command prompt. Your django-admin commands would work well.

Thanks for the suggestion.  I had not used a virtual environment because I trying to just do a basic project first.  However when I tried to setup a venv, I was able to create the project "python -m venv djangoProject" and I can see in vs code the directory structure created.  However when I run the command to activate, I do NOT see the project name as you normally would.  Something seems wrong with the setup, it's my son's laptop.  Just can't believe it could be this messed up.  I have verified the paths are set.  pip upgraded.  Stumped!  Cheers

Please accept as answer if this answers your original question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled.

Your answer is a recommended workaround for the question itself. But since the question does not include much information about the environment, I understand that answering it, is overhead without having follow up communication. But I wouldn't say that it answers the question.
